# Data Exchange between same iPhone App on separate devices

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am developing an app on iphone that lets user take photos, add comments & GPS location to it and send it as an email to another user.

If the recipient has installed the same app & when she clicks on the attachment the same app will launch & parse these details & show them to the recipient. (I intend to use UIDocumentInteractionController for some of the stuff here)

**Problem**: whats the best way to encode this data in a single file & then retrive it upon arrival from the email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty high level, but here are the general steps:

First, register your own file type as described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS3_2.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009337-SW8).

Then, archive your data using [NSKeyedArchiver](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047-SW1).

Next, attach it to an email using [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008200-CH1-SW2). Make sure you give it a filename that matches the file type you registered earlier.

Finally, implement [application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidFinishLaunchingWithOptions%3a) to handle the case when a user tries to open your email attachment. (Currently, it's the fourth bullet in the method documentation.)