# How to auto-open file in iPhone Mail into iphone application?

Tags: iphone, file, email

I am working on adding the capability for users to export data from my iphone app. I'd like to allow them to email it to themselves or to a friend. Is there a good way to enable the iPhone mail app to auto-open a specific type of file into a specific app? I know that I could somehow create a specific URL which would open such as myapp://www.google.com which would auto-open into my app, but can this be done with an attached file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this answer: [Data Exchange between same iPhone App on separate devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818820/data-exchange-between-same-iphone-app-on-separate-devices/3818883#3818883)